# Android automotive emulator and bumble

Tags: android-emulator, android-automotive

I'm trying to make the Android automotive emulator connect via Bluetooth with a device by using a USB Bluetooth dongle. First question : is that possible with bumble?
Second question: How can i use bumble to make it work?

I've read the documentation but I didn't understand how to use it. Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you please add links to the documentation you refer? And, did you try to set-up using bumble and met any specific issue?